# What action should two planes on a collision course take?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-technique

What are the various types of procedures for two aircraft on a collision course?

Comment: head on, as the answer describes, or at an angle? are they the same class? which airspace?

Comment: @Justintimeforfun At what angle are the two aircraft approaching each other? Which [Wake Turbulence Category](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/ICAO_Wake_Turbulence_Category) are they in? In which [Airspace Class](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Classification_of_Airspace) are they flying?

Comment: @Bianfable to narrow the field, lets say USA or international airspace

Comment: FULL RIGHT RUDDER!!  Oh wait, that's for ships.

Comment: USA is not an airspace. Is it class A,B,C,D,E, or?

Comment: @Federico, actually FAA knows what is the US airspace, and expects the same from pilots, cf. "[Entering, Exiting and Flying in United States Airspace](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/airspace/)"

Comment: @mins sure, but has no relevance on this question, since the answer mostly depends on the class, not the country. but ok, now this is a duplicate of a question that specifies VFR.

Answer (score 4):

[14 CFR 91.113(e)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=pt14.2.91&rgn=div5#se14.2.91_1113):

> *Approaching head-on*. When aircraft are approaching each other head-on, or nearly so, each pilot of each aircraft shall alter course
> to the right.

There are also directions in 91.113 for right of way if the two aircraft are converging, overtaking or landing. I don’t know if you also consider those a “collision course” or not.